# How to preserve wires during Yosys ABC implementation step

Tags: synthesis, yosys

I am implementing a simple circuit and want to preserve some wires during implementation using Yosys ABC. I am synthesizing using **synth_ice40**. I am using (* keep *) in my Verilog code to preserve the wires but I have noticed that after TECHMAP pass, the wires are removed and I can not see them anymore when I View my text file using **ice40_viewer**.

Could someone please provide a solution or comment on why it is happening this way?